# TypeElement vs TypeMirror as data models for Java annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm working on a code generator with annotation processing, and divided the logic into 2 steps:

1. Analyze the annotated element and create data model, and
2. Use the data model to generate code using JavaPoet.

The annotation processing API provides us `TypeMirror`s in most cases. From what I've seen online, using `TypeElement` in data models seems like a good practice (which can be obtained from `TypeMirror`).

However JavaPoet in most cases accept `TypeMirror`s directly, and converting them as `TypeElement` for the data model seems unnecessary.

Is there an advantage of one vs another as data model?

Answer (score 9):

The types represent different levels of abstraction. `TypeElement` represent the class, declared in the code, while `TypeMirror` represents that class' specific usage.

For example:

```java
class Foo {
    public void hello() {
    }
}

class Bar {
    public void hello(Foo foo) {
    }
}
```

In this example there will be 2 instances of `TypeElement` - for each one of the declared classes. Also there will be 2 instances of `ExecutableElement`, representing each one of the methods (`A.hello` and `B.hello`).

If you will take a look at the `ExecutableElement` of `B.hello()`, there will be information about method parameters and their types, while in this case, the types will be represented with `TypeMirror`. From `TypeMirror` you always can get corresponding `TypeElement`.

`TypeElement` - represents class declaration and contains all the information about the declaration itself

`TypeMirror` - represents the occurance (the specific usage) of the class in the code and has all the information, which is specific to that occurance. From the occurance you always can get the declaration, *but not vice versa*.

Despite, both entities (`TypeElement` and `TypeMirror`) might look representing the same entities at the first glance, but that's not true. Each one of them has some information, which is available only on that specific level of abstraction.

For example: annotations of the declared class or method - are available in corresponding `TypeElement`/`ExecutableElement`, but not in `TypeMirror`.

Another important aspect of difference is generics:

```java
class Foo<T> {
    public void hello() {
    }
}

class Bar {
    public void hello(Foo<String> foo) {
    }
}
```

In this example, the `TypeElement` of Foo will have information about type *parameters*, their constraints, bounds, etc.

But `TypeMirror` of the `B.hello`'s first parameter will have specific type argument (`String`), which was used in this specific occurance of using of `Foo` class